# Swift starting app without main storyboard crashes

Tags: swift

I am trying to start an app without the use of storyboards. I deleted the storyboard file and removed the Info.plist line for initializing a storyboard. However, the code below fails on the line indicated.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
        var viewController = GameViewController()
        navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        window!.makeKeyWindow()
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible() // fails here

        return true
    }

}
```

This is what comes up when it crashes:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x10041a86c:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!
0x10041a870:  stp    fp, lr, [sp, #16]
0x10041a874:  add    fp, sp, #16
0x10041a878:  mov    x8, x1
0x10041a87c:  mov    x19, x0
0x10041a880:  cbz    x19, 0x10041a8a4          ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 56
0x10041a884:  nop    
0x10041a888:  nop    
0x10041a88c:  ldr    x1, #163108               ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x10041a890:  mov    x0, x19
0x10041a894:  mov    x2, x8
0x10041a898:  bl     0x10041cf30               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x10041a89c:  tbnz   w0, #0, 0x10041a8a8       ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 60
0x10041a8a0:  brk    #1 // Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10041a8a0)
0x10041a8a4:  movz   x19, #0
0x10041a8a8:  mov    x0, x19
0x10041a8ac:  ldp    fp, lr, [sp, #16]
0x10041a8b0:  ldp    x20, x19, [sp], #32
0x10041a8b4:  ret
```

This is when using an iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1.

The same thing works in Objective-C, IIRC, so is it a swift thing or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: This doesn't fail when I replace `GameViewController` (which is a SpriteKit view controller) with a generic `UIViewController`

Comment: The "this doesn't fail when" part should be straightforward to you and immediately point you to the source of a failure.

Comment: The problem lies in `GameViewController`, not `AppDelegate`. Please do some debugging and return with results.

Comment: Aha the problem is that the `GameViewController`'s view was not a `SKView`. To fix it I added a new `SKView` to the view.

Comment: For anyone in the future, use `view = SKView(frame: view.bounds)` in your `SpriteKit` `viewDidLoad()` before you set the view.